# brew doctor warning: additional scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, homebrew

When running `brew doctor` I'm getting this caveat, and it is mildly annoying as I'm not quite sure how to solve it. Any ideas?

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config
```

Comment: Delete them?  It's just warning you they exist.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your comment. Any idea on how I can find them to delete them?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't just up and do it, but `rm -f /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/*-config` will make quick work of it.  You might need to preface the command with `sudo` if your user doesn't own those files.  Do you have any idea what it is?  Just guessing from the name, have you downloaded any of [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com)'s Perl, Python, etc interpreters maybe?

Comment: I'm using Ruby and that I believe ships with an interpreter, might that be it? I'm sure you know far better than I do because this is new to me.

Comment: [Take a look here](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/brew-doctor-errors-homebrew-help-please), it looks like you're not alone with this particular error.

Comment: See my answer below, looks like others have had this issue as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brew doctor - "warning: unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406484/brew-doctor-warning-unbrewed-header-files-were-found-in-usr-local-include)