# Issue understanding Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew, greenlets

After running `brew doctor`, I get this error related to a header file that I'm not sure about. I don't know what `greenlet` is, so I'm apprehensive to remove it as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406484/brew-doctor-warning-unbrewed-header-files-were-found-in-usr-local-include).

```
Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/python2.7/greenlet/greenlet.h
```

Please answer the following questions:

**1. What does the error `Unbrewed header files` actually mean?**

**2. Should I remove the file listed in the error?**

Comment: `unbrewed` means that the file was not installed by brew and thus is not under control of homebew, despite of being in a location that is used by homebrew. If you do not see problems, I would not worry too much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Unbrewed header files" indicates that there are header files in the Homebrew tree (by default, `/usr/local`) that Homebrew itself did not put there. Likely they were put there by some other software you installed (in this case, python-greenlet).

If you are sure you don't have the software that requires those header files installed anymore, you can safely remove them. Otherwise, you should leave them alone. They could potentially cause problems if Homebrew has to install software with files with the same path, but that probably won't happen.

Answer (score 6):

The straightforward answer:

1. It means there is a header file in that location. Homebrew (unfortunately) uses `usr/local` by default which is used by other applications as well. In this case, `pip` added it as part of the `python-greenlet` installation.
2. No. See the question at the python-greenlet repo [greenlet cause brew warning!](https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/75).

On avoiding the warnings: you could probably use a custom installation prefix. The homebrew installation instructions ([2016 Apr 3 permalink](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/276a797d37fa057f935ba671bca04163389046f1/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md)) say you can do that, but warn against it. In practice I've heard that issues are quite rarely encountered.